# Google smtp mail shows gmail as sender

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5.3

I've implemented google smtp in my laravel app for sending mails from contact form. Contact form does work smoothly but mails that i get from contact form labels gmail id as the sender although I have configured to use email from form input to label as sender.Below is my code for handling contact form:

```
        $data = array(
        'fname' => $request->fname,
        'lname' => $request->lname,
        'phone' => $request->phone,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'subject' => $request->subject,
        'bodyMessage' => $request->message
        );

    Mail::send('emails.contact', $data, function($message) use ($data){
        $message->from($data['email']);
        $message->to('mail@domain.com');
        $message->subject($data['subject']);
    });
```

Here is the screen shot of mail i got from contact form[image: screenshot]. During development I used mailtrap and didn't had this problem.

Comment: I believe you need to use the gmail api instead, if I remember correctly. https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

Comment: Perhaps you could set their address in the replyTo header: $message->replyTo($data['email']);

Comment: I don't believe google allows you to overwrite the from header. The most I've been able to change is the name only, but not the underlying email address. So you could make it appear to come from "Your Customers Name<but.your.service.account.address@gmail.com>"